# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression when sum(col)

Tags: oracle, group-by, sum

```
SELECT 
    INVOICEM.EMP_NO,
    EMPLOYEES.EMP_NAME,
    INVOICEM.INV_NO,
    SUM(INVOICEM.SUM_AMT),
    INVOICEM.SAL_DATE,
    INVOICEM.BRANCH
FROM INVOICEM JOIN EMPLOYEES
ON INVOICEM.EMP_NO = EMPLOYEES.EMP_NO
GROUP BY INVOICEM.EMP_NO,EMP_NAME
```

Help me

Answer (score 0):

You can only select field which are in group by statement or aggregation function in oracle:

```
SELECT INVOICEM.EMP_NO,EMPLOYEES.EMP_NAME,SUM(INVOICEM.SUM_AMT)
FROM INVOICEM JOIN EMPLOYEES
ON INVOICEM.EMP_NO = EMPLOYEES.EMP_NO
GROUP BY INVOICEM.EMP_NO,EMP_NAME
```